# simplify crud button

Tags: c#, winforms

hi i would like to simplify my CRUD buttons in my based form. For this, i would thinks convert all that to a custom control is the best practice.

I referred to the Rocket framework, and this is what he wrote as below. He create a custom control which has CRUD buttons and also search button, and loadAll button align in a same row. Then when we need the certain particular button, we can just grab the location of that button like what we did for website image where we make all the images to become 1 image. This sounds good to me.

Questions:
1) How do i apply this custom control button to my GUI form?
2) How can simplify the confirmation message and prompt result message to user for my CRUD button? i felt it redundant to write `"Are you sure to save/ delete"` on all my crud button many times upon pressing the save button and `"This record is saved successfully / failed"` after the save() event. Anyway i can simplify this by putting it to the based form CRUD custom control? E.g when user press Save button, it will run the based form confirmation message and it will continue run back the Save() event at the datamodel and back to the based form to get the Result message " successsfully save".

```
 public partial class AdminController : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler AddUpdateClick;
    public event EventHandler DeleteClick;
    public event EventHandler CreateNewClick;
    public event EventHandler RefreshClick;
    public event EventHandler FilterClick;
    public event EventHandler LoadAllClick;
    public AdminController()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DeleteClick != null)
            DeleteClick(sender, e);
    }

    private void buttonAddUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (AddUpdateClick != null)
            AddUpdateClick(sender, e);
    }

    private void buttonCreateNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CreateNewClick != null)
            CreateNewClick(sender, e);
    }

    private void buttonLoadAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (LoadAllClick != null)
            LoadAllClick(sender, e);
    }

    private void buttonFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FilterClick != null)
            FilterClick(sender, e);
    }

    private void buttonRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RefreshClick != null)
            RefreshClick(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Please advice

Answer (score 1):

1) Once compiled a User Control will be available from the Toolbox. Look in the Toolbox's top most group.

2) The following code invokes the AdminController's DeleteClick event if it has been hooked:

```
if (DeleteClick != null)
    DeleteClick(sender, e);
```

To implement a confirmation message before invoking the delete event consider changing the above code to:

```
    if (DeleteClick != null)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to save?", "Please Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            DeleteClick(sender, e);
        }
    }
```

To implement the success / fail message the delegate that is hooking the event will to let  AdminController know that the update was successful or not by passing back a boolean value. This can be achived using a custom EventArgs class

```
public class AdminControllerEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public bool Success;

    public AdminControllerEventArgs() : base()
    {
        Success = true;
    }
}
```

and changing the declarations of the events in AdminController to use AdminControllerEventArgs:

```
public partial class AdminController : UserControl
{
    public delegate void AdminControllerEvent(object sender, AdminControllerEventArgs e);

    public event AdminControllerEvent AddUpdateClick;
    public event AdminControllerEvent DeleteClick;
```

Then the value of success can be tested as follows:

```
    AdminControllerEventArgs e = new AdminControllerEventArgs();

    if (DeleteClick != null)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to save?", "Please Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            DeleteClick(sender, e);

            if (adminControllerEventArgs.Success)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This record is saved successfully.");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This record is saved failed.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Delegates hooking to the new events will need to set `e.Success = false` when the database update fails.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. I tried your code but the `if (adminControllerEventArgs.Success)` does not have Success. I changed to  public static bool Success; and it works. As for what you said on `e.Success = false`, do u meant i have to put it to every function which it returns failed?

Comment: hi i am not able to build after i added your code. the ` DeleteClick(sender, e);` has some invalid arguement. I think that is due to the `public delegate void AdminControllerEvent(object sender, AdminControllerEventArgs e);
` Could you help ?

Comment: I tried changed the  private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) to become `private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, AdminControllerEventArgs e)`, but this give error on ` this.btnDelete.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnDelete_Click);`  with "Error 2 No overload for 'btnDelete_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler' "

Comment: Hi Belinq, I have added an extra line of code at the beginning of my last code sample which creates an instance of AdminControllerEventArgs, this should resolve one of your issues.