# Error on my user control

Tags: c#, winforms

HI could anyone advice how to solve this error?
 I got the response from this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429841/simplify-crud-button/5431378#comment-6585267) but unfortunately there is no more response from the author. So i decided to post here again with his solution.

**ERROR:** Error    1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'project1.Utility.AdminController.AdminControllerEvent' to 'System.EventHandler'

Error happen when i want to hook the

`//btnDelete.Click += new AdminControllerEvent(btnDelete_Click);`

```
namespace project1.Utility
{   
    public partial class AdminController : UserControl
    {
        public delegate void AdminControllerEvent(object sender, AdminControllerEventArgs e);

    public event AdminControllerEvent SaveClick;
    public event AdminControllerEvent DeleteClick;

    public AdminController()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //btnDelete.Click += new AdminControllerEvent(btnDelete_Click);
    }

    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, AdminControllerEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DeleteClick != null)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show(CoreMessages.DeleteAsk, CoreMessages.DeleteAsk, MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                DeleteClick(sender, e);

                if (AdminControllerEventArgs.Success)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(CoreMessages.DeleteSuccess, CoreMessages.Successful, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(CoreMessages.DeleteFailed, CoreMessages.Failed, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class AdminControllerEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public static bool Success;

    public AdminControllerEventArgs()
        : base()
    {
        Success = true;
    }
}
```

}

---

In my Form delete UI

```
 private void adminController_DeleteClick(object sender, AdminControllerEventArgs e)
    {
        Repository.Delete(user);
    }
```

Comment: Click is already a event with Button which has a different signature than the one you have defined so it won't be able to map it up

Comment: The reason i added the new class `AdminControllerEventArgs : EventArgs` so that in my  if (AdminControllerEventArgs.Success)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(CoreMessages.DeleteSuccess, CoreMessages.Successful, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                } i can straight away know whether the save is succcess or not. The reason for this is so that i don have to pass the flag(boolean) back to that class

Comment: But you are using the same button class which uses the standard signature for registering the method, How will it know to call your implemented class. Hope you got my point

Comment: hmm.. sould logic. Then would be the best way to tell the delete user control button that the delete is success or fail without passing the flag.

Comment: You could do that by setting a property which could be used

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the reply. I have added the solution provided by Adrian Toman at the link above. i am trying to use his way to enhance the user control. But it seems not the solution based on the comments below. Could anyone advice on the solution?

Comment: I would recommend putting that as a specific different question which would help getting better approaches for your problem

Answer (score 1):

The event `Click` expects a handler implementing the signature described by `System.EventHandler`. That won't work - you have to change the signature or implement your own additional handler for `Click` that raises another event calling your custom handler. I'm not really sure what you're tryin to do here mixing event handler code with other UI messages etc.

Comment: I got the response from this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429841/simplify-crud-button/5431378#comment-6585267 but unfortunately there is no more response from the author. So i decided to post here again with his solution. Could you take a look at his code?

Comment: The linked example always uses `EventHandler` for the signature which will work - your issue is trying to use a custom one.

Comment: I think he did not use the EventHandler. Look at the line `public event AdminControllerEvent DeleteClick;` So when it comes to the line `DeleteClick(sender, e);`, the DeleteClick( , ) would need the (object sender,AdminControllerEventArgs e)

Comment: He doesn't add such a handler to the button's `Click` event. He raises his custom event with the custom paramete - but not using built-in events.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the signature of the method. The button click event has no event data to pass and by convention they have two parameters.

Since it has no event data to pass it uses **EventArgs**,so since you have made your implementation the Button **Click** is unaware of that and so the error

Comment: Hey did this help with your question ?

Answer (score 0):

[Button.Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx) will raise Click event with plain `EventArgs` arguments. You can't expect `Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` to work with more specific method signature (using `AdminControllerEventArgs` arguments). How do you convert EventArgs to AdminControllerEventArgs?

Imagine it worked tho. What happens when:

- Button.Click creates `new EventArgs()`
- Button.Click calls your `btnDelete_Click(this, args)`
- `args` are expected to be of type `AdminControllerEventArgs`
- ...but are in fact `EventArgs`
- your code in `btnDelete_Click` tries to access `args.Success` property
- ...which isn't there, because `EventArgs` doesn't have one

Unfortunatelly, you'll need a workaround for this.